# Rolling min of a Pandas Series without window / cumulative minimum / expanding min

Tags: python, pandas, min, accumulate

I'm looking for a way to calculate with Python Pandas rolling(*) min of a Series without window.

Let's consider the following `Series`

```
In [26]: s = pd.Series([10, 12, 14, 9, 10, 8, 16, 20])
Out[26]:
0    10
1    12
2    14
3     9
4    10
5     8
6    16
7    20
dtype: int64
```

I would like to get a Series like

```
0    10
1    10
2    10
3     9
4     9
5     8
6     8
7     8
dtype: int64
```

I tried

```
s.rolling().min()
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
TypeError: rolling() missing 1 required positional argument: 'window'
```

I did this

```
r = s.copy()
val_min = r.iloc[0]
for i, (idx, val) in enumerate(r.iteritems()):
    if i > 0:
        if val < val_min:
            val_min = val
        else:
            r[idx] = val_min
```

and have a correct answer

```
In [30]: r
Out[30]:
0    10
1    10
2    10
3     9
4     9
5     8
6     8
7     8
dtype: int64
```

but I think a Pandas method should probably exist (and be much more efficient) or if it doesn't exist, it should probably be implemented.

(*) "rolling" may not be the appropriate term, maybe it should be named instead a "local" min.

Edit: it's in fact named a cumulative minimum or expanding min

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`Series.cummin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummin.html):

```
print(s.cummin())
0    10
1    10
2    10
3     9
4     9
5     8
6     8
7     8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Would there be a way to also the the index of the minimum values?

Comment: @EduardoReis - Do you think `s1 = s.cummin()` and then `s1.index = s1.index.to_series().groupby(s1.ne(s1.shift()).cumsum()).transform('first')` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.minimum.accumulate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.accumulate.html):

```
import numpy as np

pd.Series(np.minimum.accumulate(s.values))

0    10
1    10
2    10
3     9
4     9
5     8
6     8
7     8
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use `s.expanding.min` (see [`Series.expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.expanding.html)):

```
s.expanding().min()
```

Output:

```
0    10.0
1    10.0
2    10.0
3     9.0
4     9.0
5     8.0
6     8.0
7     8.0
```

Comment: it's quite odd to notice that `s.expanding().min()` doesn't preserve type (but converts `int64` to `float64`)